# anyways to receive data from the GPS module with GSM/GPRS

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm, netduino

Am doing a project using the GPS. the main scenario is to display the position of the object in the maps.

Scenario : am plan to use a GPS Antenna in the Arduino/Netduino board. where i will code to post GPS location data to the server using http/soap.

Am comfortable with both codings(Arduino/Netduino). but am not able to choose the right one. which board i can use  Netduio / Arduino, which is better in the power consumption and performance

Comment: What GPS module? What receiver? Less power consumption than what? What database, running on what? Is the GPS module attached to the database thing, or is it remote?

Comment: Please understand that in your question, there is a lot of missing context. Re-read it and try to take into account how it would look like to someone who has no idea what it is that you're doing. Can you post a block diagram of what you want to do? It seems to me that you may have some basic misconceptions about GPS and we'll need more information to clear that up.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [site](http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/gps/). They have few easy to use GSP boards. You can connect on those modules via i2c or UART, so Arduino board should be sufficient.